# kendo ui grid bottom border with height overlaps

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Why kendo grid shown to me like this:

[image: kendo grid bottom border issue]

Comment: Help those that may help you: would you care to link to a fiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I can't do it just right now (at work), but should add fiddel as I became free, I think there is people who faced with this problem.

Comment: How did you set the height of the grid?

Comment: Hi @OnaBai , nice to meet you. I use MVVM to give height: `data-height="200"`

Comment: I run into some strange issues with grids and height.  Try wrapping your grid inside another div and see if that helps.

Comment: @RobinGiltner, hi dude, it is already wrapped by some dives. thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you post code for how you initialize the grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are resizing the grid manually, you must resize both the grid and data-area height. If you have a tool bar, you may also need to take this into account. Try this when you are resizing your grid:

```
 var gridElement = $("#gridElementName");
 var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");
 var toolbar = gridElement.find(".k-toolbar");
 var thead = gridElement.find("table[role='grid'] thead");
 var newGridHeight;
 var newDataAreaHeight;

 newGridHeight = $(document).height() - offsetValueOne;
 newDataAreaHeight = newGridHeight - toolbar.height() - thead.height() - offsetValueTwo;
 dataArea.height(newDataAreaHeight);
 dataArea.css("max-height", newDataAreaHeight);
 gridElement.height(newGridHeight);
```

OffsetValueOne should be larger than OffsetValueTwo. In your code, it seems that the data-area and the grid height are not matching up correctly. Hope this helps. Good luck.